# How to get Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() from libGDX class?

Tags: android, libgdx, environment

I have a game very much like flappy bird. I just want to save highscore in a text file. To do so I first need to get directory path.

[image]

Here you can see I am unable to call Environment to get my external storage directory. Why is this happening?

Is it because I am calling Environment from core directory? If it so how can i get the directory from this class?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is because you are calling Environment from core directory.
You can in android directory have:

```
public static String foo="bar";
```

And access from core class with `ClassName.foo`.

**EDIT:** But in your case, I will try to use some libGDX data write/read instead of calling Android. Please check this: [LibGDX documentation](http://www.github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling)

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Later on, I really didn't understand what should I do to get directory name. Could you be more specific? For example, in this case if you look at the screen shot that I've posted what should I type in the given class to getExternalStorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath ?

Comment: Well, my answer is way how to access to some class variables from another. But in your case, I will try to use some libGDX data write/read instead of calling Android. Please check this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

Comment: Yes the link is really helpful. I think the answer is hidden somewhere in there. I'll search in it and I believe I'll find the solution. If I find it I'll share here to be helpful to others. Thank you!

Comment: I've expand my question, accept it if it is help you.